# Extract item embedded in a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have this tuple:

```
(Float64Index([2439532.59375], dtype='float64', name='from_datetime'), 
    array(['2439532.593750000000000'], dtype=object), array([2439532]), array([243953259375]))
```

How can I extract the final array value: "243953259375"

I tried multiple versions of  nth item from a tuple, t[n], but get

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

thanks

Comment: What did you type to output `(Float64Index([2439532.59375], dtype='float64', name='from_datetime'), 
    array(['2439532.593750000000000'], dtype=object), array([2439532]), array([243953259375]))`. That isn't really a tuple. What is the actual tuple(s) of values? Kind of confusing.

Comment: I used a function on a dataframe: _,_,_,dfdatetime['from_dtkey'] = jday(dtinput=dfdatetime['from_datetime'])

Comment: = _,_,_,dfdatetime['from_dtkey'] = jday(dtinput=dfdatetime['from_datetime'])
from_dtkey=dfdatetime['from_dtkey'].values[0]
print(from_dtkey)

type(k)
k = _,_,_,dfdatetime['from_dtkey'] = jday(dtinput=dfdatetime['from_datetime'])
from_dtkey=dfdatetime['from_dtkey'].values[0]
print(from_dtkey)
​
type(k)
243953259375
tuple

Comment: I want to access k directly - I print the type() of K and I get a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

you access your 4th by `t[3]` and then you can access the value by `[0]`

```
from pandas import Float64Index, array
t = (Float64Index([2439532.59375], dtype='float64', name='from_datetime'),
    array(['2439532.593750000000000'], dtype=object), array([2439532]), array([243953259375]))
print(t[3][0])  # --> 243953259375
```